# Route Action Method in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I am trying to do a before-action check on a route. Therefore I set up a middleware as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Route;

class PermissionMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   list(, $action) = explode('@', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName());

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

In my controller, I do as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Blog;
use Image;
use File;
use Route;

class BlogController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth','permission']);
}


public function create()
{       
   .......
   .......
}
```

And my route is as follows:

```
Route::get('create/news',"BlogController@create");
```

However, when I navigate to the route, it displays an error as follows:

[image]

Giving an exception as follows:

> FatalErrorException Call to a member function getActionName() on null
>   in PermissionMiddleware.php (line 19)

I have tried to no avail to resolve this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Read again the error message and you'll find the problem.

The error is:

```
FatalErrorException Call to a member function getActionName() on null in PermissionMiddleware.php (line 19)
```

On line 19, I guess you have this:

```
list(, $action) = explode('@', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName());
```

That means that error comes from here: "Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName()".

Route::getCurrentRoute() returns null. So you call the method "getActionName()" from null.

Please check the method "getCurrentRoute()" in order to fix the problem.
Good luck.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Route::getCurrentRoute() returns null and I don't know the reason for that. Any clue to why that could happen?

Comment: Thank you but I actually saw that before. But what I am looking for is the routeAction() and not the routeName() and that link you referred me to is discussing the routeName() rather